# php curl post json data contains a null entry for parameter

Tags: php, function, api, curl

i've create a php function to make a post `json` data request using `curl`

My Code :

```
$url = 'http://77.42.154.142:90/home/test/GetNewCustomer';
     $data = array("UpdatedOn" => "1/23/2004 1:00AM","CreatedOn" => "1/23/2015 1:00AM");
     $fields = json_encode($data);

     $post = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'sduser: 34EE0A61-F3A5-4E21-86D3-C7B7DAF9C8F9913982A9-3025-4C37-8093-B664B9310F91',
      'Content-Length:'.strlen($fields)
     ));
     curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($fields)));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
     //curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
     $result = curl_exec($post);

     // for debugging
     var_dump(curl_getinfo($post), $result);

    //  if(false === $result) { // request failed
    //       die('Error: "' . curl_error($post) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($post));
    // }

     curl_close($post);
```

But i've got this response `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter`

Any Suggestion ?

Comment: have a look at the resulting command that gets executed. Most likely the URL is malformed.

Comment: @IgorT.  i've update my url post